# Get an URL of selector's option and add it as a link to Submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I broke my head trying to get an URL value of an option in my selector and add it to the Submit button so that when an user choose an option 1 its URL is added to the Submit button url.

For example if the option 1 URL is `<option><a href="https://example.com/1">1</a></option>` the button should follow to the link `https://example.com/1`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose an option</option>
        <option><a href="https://example.com/1">1</a></option>
        <option><a href="https://example.com/2">2</a></option>
        <option><a href="https://example.com/3">3</a></option>
        <option><a href="https://example.com/4">4</a></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My js knowledge is poor unfortunately so I would much appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't put html inside `<option>`. It is a text only element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Vanilla JS solution:

---

**You can set the href attribute of the anchor tag based on the selection at runtime.**

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.querySelector('#inputState').addEventListener('change', function(event) {

    document.querySelector('#anchorSubmit').setAttribute('href', `https://www.example.com/${event.currentTarget.value}`);

  });

}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected value="">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="anchorSubmit">
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I think this would help you - 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myFarm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>Choose an option</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#inputState').on('change', function() {
          $("#myFarm").attr("action", "https://example.com/"+ $(this).val()).submit();
      })
    })
 </script>
```

Comment: As soon as I submit the form, the page refreshes and I see the following url https://www.example.com/?

Answer (score 1):

If i right understand your question - you need to redirect user by the chosen `<option>` url.

For this you can do:

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on('submit', '#myForm', (event) => {
           event.stopPropagation();
           const selectElement = $(this).find('#inputState');

           if(selectElement.val()){
              location.href = selectElement.val();
           }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="inputState">State</label>
          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Choose an option</option>
            <option value="http://url/1">1</option>
            <option value="http://url/2">2</option>
            <option value="http://url/3">3</option>
            <option value="http://url/4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

But if you wantsubmit form to url from `<option>` value, you can do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('submit', '#myForm', (event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();
          const selectElement = $('#inputState');

          if(selectElement.val()){
              $(this).attr('action', selectElement.val());
              $(this).submit();
          }
      });
    });
 </script>
```

upd. moved code from first example to snippet

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. Unfortunately when I'm trying to submit the form, the page refreshes and nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake, it was typo in for id tag. And url in value